# Convert from Object<const T> to Object<t>

Tags: c++, casting

Assume we have a template class:

```
class Object<T>
```

And one instance of a variable:

```
Object<const IQuestion> qobj1(new Question());
Object<IQuestion> qobj2(new Question());
```

I would like to make a call to the function `areEqual` like this:

```
areEqual(question1, question2).
```

How to make a call to a function:

```
bool areEqual(const Object<IQuestion>& rhs, const Object<IQuestion>& rhs) const
```

Considering that variables are slightly different?

I assume that this somehow can be achieved with `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `Object<X>` and `Object<Y>` are different, unrelated classes unless `X` and `Y` are exactly the same type. You will have to make a  function for converting between the two ; or perhaps stop using `Object<const IQuestion>` at all.

Comment: I cannot provide an overload, neither I have control over the incoming parameters. I guess I could clone the const variable and build one more instance of Object<X>.

Comment: See if you can use a new overload `bool areEqual(const Object<const X>& lhs, const Object<Y>& rhs) const`

Answer (score 1):

The following probably does something similar to what you are looking for:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>::value, bool>
areEqual(const Object<T>& lhs, const Object<U>& rhs) {
    // T and U are the same type, put aside cv qualifiers and references
    // if you know what's a meaningful way to compare them, do that
    // note that here T and U can still have different cv-qualifiers 
}
```

See a minimal, working example on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f4f472ffaf4160).